# Joining two tables and calculating divide-SUM from the resulting table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table that looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+------+
| id_instrument | id_data_label |   Date    | Value | Note |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+------+
|             1 |            57 | 1.10.2010 |   200 | NULL |
|             1 |            57 | 2.10.2010 |   190 | NULL |
|             1 |            57 | 3.10.2010 |   202 | NULL |
|               |               |           |       |      |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+------+
```

And the other that looks like this:

```
+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+
| id_fundamental | id_instrument | id_data_label | quarter_code | value |  AnnDate  | Note |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+
|              1 |             1 |            20 |        20101 | 3     | 28.2.2010 | NULL |
|              2 |             1 |            20 |        20102 | 4     | 1.8.2010  | NULL |
|              3 |             1 |            20 |        20103 | 5     | 2.11.2010 | NULL |
|                |               |               |              |       |           |      |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+
```

What I would like to do is to merge/join these two tables in one in a way that I get something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|    Date    | Table1.Value | Table2.Value | AnnDate  | quarter_code |
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| 1.10.2010. |          200 |            3 | 1.8.2010 |        20102 |
| 2.10.2010. |          190 |            3 | 1.8.2010 |        20102 |
| 3.10.2010. |          202 |            3 | 1.8.2010 |        20102 |
|            |              |              |          |              |
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

So the idea is to order them by Date from Table1 and since Table2 Values only change on the change of AnnDate we populate the Resulting table with same values from Table2.

After that I would like to go through the resulting table and create another (Final table) with the following.

On Date 1.10.2010. take last 4 AnnDates (so it would be 1.8.2010. and f.e. 20.3.2010. 30.1.2010. 15.11.2009) and Table2 values on those AnnDate. Make SUM of those 4 values and then divide the Table1 Value with that SUM.

So we would get something like:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Date    |                          FinalValue                           |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.10.2010 | 200/(Table2.Value on 1.8.2010+Table2.Value on 20.3.2010 +...) |
|           |                                                               |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way this can be done?

EDIT:

Hmm yes now I see that I really didn't do a good job explaining it. 
What I wanted to say is 
I try INNER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT TableOne.Date, TableOne.Value, TableTwo.Value, TableTwo.AnnDate, TableTwo.quarter_code 
FROM TableOne 
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.id_intrument=TableTwo.id_instrument WHERE TableOne.id_data_label = somevalue AND TableTwo.id_data_label = somevalue AND date > xxx AND date < yyy
```

And this inner join returns 2620*40 rows which means for every AnnDate from table2 it returns all Date from table1.

What I want is to return 2620 values with Dates from Table1
Values from table1 on that date and Values from table2 that respond to that period of dates

f.e.
Table1:

```
+-------+-------+
| Date  | Value |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | a     |
|     2 | b     |
|     3 | c     |
|     4 | d     |
+-------+-------+
```

Table2

```
+-------+---------+
| Value | AnnDate |
+-------+---------+
| x     |       1 |
| y     |       4 |
+-------+---------+
```

Resulting table:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| Date  | ValueT1 | ValueT2 |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     1 | a       | x       |
|     2 | b       | x       |
|     3 | c       | x       |
|     4 | d       | y       |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: it is not clear enough how you are joining Table1 and Table 2 together in order to get the intermediate table (the one with 5 cols).

Comment: Okay let me try and clear it up.

I would like to join them in a way that the first column of the resulting table is Date from Table1. Second column is Value from Table2 and thrid column is Value from Table3. The problem is table1 has 2620 rows and table2 has 40 rows. values in table2 only change on AnnDate.

So I want resulting table to have 2620 rows with table1 values and values from table2 to be filled for dates where there are no change with the last value. I dont know if you managed to understand me. Sorry.

Comment: Second column is Value from Table2 and thrid column is Value from Table3? Where is Table3?

Comment: Table2 sorry my mistake.

Comment: It is not clear enough what values from Table2 are used to fill the intermediate table. Which one of the 40 rows of Table2 you pick and why?

Comment: Look at the EDIT in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JOIN statement for your first query. Try:

```
SELECT TableOne.Date, TableOne.Value, TableTwo.Value, TableTwo.AnnDate, TableTwo.quarter_code FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo
ON TableOne.id_intrument=TableTwo.id_instrument;
```

Comment: I already tried that. I dont get what I want. I get Date remaining fixed and Table1.Values fixed while Table2.Values are changing which should not happen.

Comment: Can you provide in your question what happens when you have tried that query?

Comment: So I actually did this:

SELECT TableOne.Date, TableOne.Value, TableTwo.Value, TableTwo.AnnDate, TableTwo.quarter_code FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo
ON TableOne.id_intrument=TableTwo.id_instrument
WHERE TableOne.id_data_label = somevalue
AND TableTwo.id_data_label = somevalue
AND date > xxx AND date < yyy

and I got too much values. I cant even explain what they represent. I got 52120 values and I should have got 2620 values.

Comment: Because there is no join on Date and AnnDate we get for every AnnDate all values from table1 so where we should get 2620 values we get 2620*40 values.